# R stat Define angle of labels on x for assign label text with index values

Tags: r, plot, label

I am finishing with my script, but I cannot set an angle for x labels. I would like to use it for my data in specific index position:

INPUT:

> xlabel <- (0,100,200,250,336)
>
> xlabel.popis <- ("TATA","MAMA","OND","KOKO","LOLO")

OUTPUT:
Will be plotted xlabel.popis on specific xlabel postion on x axis (x axis is index line (0..500)) and xlabel.popis will have vertical rotation.

I tried:

```
plot(read.table(files2[i],header=F,sep="\t")$V7,main=file_bez2[i], axes=FALSE)
xlabel <- (0,100,200,250,336)
xlabel.popis <- ("TATA","MAMA","OND","KOKO","LOLO")
axis(1, at=seq_along(xlabel),labels=as.character(xlabel.popis, las=2, cex.label=90))
```

or I tried no axis but `mtext(as.character(xlabel.popis),side=1,line=1.1,at=xlabel,srt=90)`
Nothing worked, could you help me, It will be better for me with axis definition.And par() definiton did not work too.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add labels with the `text` function after a call to `axis`.

#### example:

```
xlabel <- c(0,100,200,250,336)
xlabel.popis <- c("TATA","MAMA","OND","KOKO","LOLO")

plot(range(xlabel), c(1,1), t="l", xaxt="n", xlab="")
axis(1, at=xlabel, labels=FALSE)
text(x=xlabel, y=par()$usr[3]-0.1*(par()$usr[4]-par()$usr[3]),
labels=xlabel.popis, srt=45, adj=1, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

If you just want 90° rotation, consider the `las` argument:

```
plot(range(xlabel), c(1,1), t="l", xaxt="n", xlab="")
axis(1, at=xlabel, labels=xlabel.popis, las=2)
```

[image]

Comment: The second reason is the best for me, thank you so much. First one is working too.